# Jquery Bootgrid Modal for edit not appears

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-bootgrid

good afternoon.

I'm working with  jQuery-bootgrid. In the last column I have two buttons for Edit/Delete of the row-content.
Delete works nice, but when I want to edit something, the **modal dont appear**
idk what else to do lol :(

Here its the function I have in

funciones.js

```
 $(document).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function()
  {
   productTable.find(".update").on("click", function(event)
    {
    var id_matricula = $(this).data("row-id");
     $.ajax({
     url:"fetch_single.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:{id_matricula:id_matricula},
     dataType:"json",
     success:function(data)
     {

      $('#productModal').modal('show');
      $('#nomAlu').val(data.nomAlu);
      $('#apellidoP').val(data.apellidoP);
      $('#apellidoM').val(data.apellidoM);
      $('#id_carrera').val(data.id_carrera);
      $('.modal-title').text("Edit Product");
      $('#id_matricula').val(id_matricula);
      $('#action').val("Edit");
      $('#operation').val("Edit");
   }
  });
 });
});
```

Fetch_single.php

```
<?php
  //fetch_single.php
   include("connection.php");
   if(isset($_POST["id_matricula"]))
    {
    //$output = array();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE id_matricula = 
    '".$_POST["id_matricula"]."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
   $output["id_matricula"] = $row["id_matricula"];
   $output["nomAlu"] = $row["nomAlu"];
   $output["apellidoP"] = $row["ApellidoP"];
   $output["apellidoM"] = $row["ApellidoM"];
   $output["id_carrera"] = $row["id_carrera"];
    }
  echo json_encode($output);
  }

  ?>
```

HTML index.php

```
<script src="funciones.js"></script>
<div id="productModal" class="modal fade">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <form method="post" id="product_form">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
  </button>
 <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

 <label>Matricula</label>
<input type="text" name="id_matricula" id="id_matricula" class="form-control" /> 
 <label>Nombre</label>
 <input type="text" name="nomAlu" id="nomAlu" class="form-control" />
 <label>Apellido Paterno</label>
 <input type="text" name="apellidoP" id="apellidoP" class="form-control" />
 <label>Apellido Materno</label>
 <input type="text" name="apellidoM" id="apellidoM" class="form-control" />
  <label>Selecciona Carrera</label>
 <select name="id_carrera" id="id_carrera" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Carrera</option>
  <?php echo $output; ?>
 </select>
 <br />
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see where you are declaring the element with the ID `productModal`

Comment: Oh sure, I forgot to add the rest of HTML code, it's fixed with **id=productModal**.